# Converting a string of charcters to a an array of binary values

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to create a binary representation of a string of characters but could only print them using serial.print(arr,BIN);

Is there a way to save the binary values of each char of the string to an array or even a long number?
* Working on Arduino sketch (C++) if it makes any difference.

I used this code trying to create an array but couldn't make it work:

```
void loop() {

  String Message = "Hello World";         
  int l = Message.length();
  int BinMessage[l];

  for (int j=0; Message[j] != NULL; j++){  
       BinMessage[j] = String(Message[j], BIN);
       Serial.println(BinMessage);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use [`bitRead`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/BitRead) function to read the bits of each character one by one, then store those values as characters in a new string.